# External IP not accessible through LAN

Tags: lan, wan

I can't access my server in my LAN by using my external IP address. I have no idea why. Hosts doesn't seem to be able to fix it.

Comment: You give no details of your config or what were your own efforts. It's not likely that anybody can / wants to solve this question in its current form.

Comment: What have you tried? You'd need to port forward to access it (router configuration). If you're trying SSH, forward port 22 to your server's IP (static tends to be best). You could SSH using other ports of course, most commonly 2222.

Answer (score 2):

Check that your ISP isn't blocking whatever ports you're checking.  Many ISPs (e.g., Comcast and others) have at times blocked ports they considered "commercial" on consumer residential accounts.  Ports often blocked include 80 (http), 443 (https) and 25 (smtp).

Comment: I'm reluctant to believe this is practiced in 2013. That's really shocking!

Comment: Oh, yes, it still happens.  My son ran into this with Comcast in California just a couple weeks ago, which is why it was on my mind.  Last I heard, they were going to give him a new modem with the block removed.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин Yeah, we've had so many issues with things like this and it wastes hours of time. Great suggestion Nicole +1

Comment: It's borderline censorship. One would think that such a practice would be outlawed in the land of the free.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин They just don't want you running web and mail servers unless you upgrade and pay for a commercial account.

Answer (score 0):

There is a NAT on your router more likely than not. You need to employ port forwarding in order to make services behind a NAT visible to the outside on the external IP address of your router. Portforward.com comes to mind.